# Rendering HTML inside <body> tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Not sure if it's too basic or too complicated. Can someone help render some HTML on WordPress `<body>` tag.

Here's an example.

In normal HTML case, all you have to do is add anything within the "body" tag and it will show up on page source. Something like `<body itemscope itemtype= (followed by Schema type)>`

But this is not the case with WordPress. Can someone help me with that?
I have some basic understanding of HTML, CSS and some knowledge on WordPress.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Where do you want to add text, is it in header, in page or in sidebar?

Comment: Your question or problem is unclear. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what problem you are facing?

Comment: Check Wordpress site architecture, it will tell you where to add your text. https://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Architecture_1.5

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to:- Edit header.php And add those attributes to the body.

Alternative (without editing theme files) way would be to create a plugin which adds a js that adds those attributes to body. Something like this:-

```
$("body").attr( { data-spy:"scroll", data-target:".navbar" } );
```

**EDIT** After viewing Sevi's answers. The most suitable way is

```
function wp_body_classes( $classes )
{
    $classes[] = '" spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','wp_body_classes', 999 );
```